# Здравствуйте. В CSV-файл записывается только последнее значение из списка, если кто занет подскажите почему?

Tags: python, excel, requests, beautiful-soup, selenium-webdriver

Выводит на print изаписывается в CSV-файлтолько последнее значение из списка, если кто занет подскажите почему? Код на Python:

```
import bs4
import time
import urllib.parse
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  # pip install webdriver-manager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

print('Вставьте слово или несколько слов на английском через запятую...')
boom = input()
aas = []
aas.append(boom)

for word in aas:
    words = word.split(',')
    for w in words:
        slovo = w.strip()
        with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                              options=chrome_options) as driver:  # Открываем хром
            driver.get(
                f"https://translate.yandex.ru/?source_lang=en&target_lang=ru&text={urllib.parse.quote(slovo)}")  # Открываем страницу
            time.sleep(5)  # Время на прогрузку страницы
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            translate = soup.find('div', class_='translation-container state-fadeaway')
            print(translate.text.strip())
            perevod = (translate.text.strip())
import requests  # pip install requests
import csv
import urllib.parse
from test_app import slovo, perevod
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # pip install bs4

url = f'https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/{urllib.parse.quote(slovo)}?q={urllib.parse.quote(slovo)}'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
block = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
# print(block)

zagol = block.find('div', class_='responsive_entry_center_left').find('p')
print(zagol.text.strip())
name = (zagol.text.strip())
object = block.find('div', class_='webtop').find('h1')
print(object.text.strip())
param = (object.text.strip())
transcript_1 = block.find('div', class_='webtop').find('div', class_='phons_br')
print(transcript_1.text.strip())
param_1 = (transcript_1.text.strip())
transcript_2 = block.find('div', class_='webtop').find('div', class_='phons_n_am')
print(transcript_2.text.strip())
param_2 = (transcript_2.text.strip())
# znach = block.find('span', class_='def')
# print(znach.text.strip())
characts = block.find_all('li', class_='sense')
print(characts[0].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
charact_1 = (characts[0].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
print(characts[1].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
charact_2 = (characts[1].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
print(characts[2].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
charact_3 = (characts[2].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
try:
    print(characts[3].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
    charact_4 = (characts[3].find_next('span', class_='def').text.strip())
except:
    print('None')
    charact_4 = 'None'

stprage = {'zagol': name, 'word': slovo, 'trans_1': param_1, 'trans_2': param_2, 'perevod': perevod,
           'charact_1': charact_1, 'charact_2': charact_2, 'charact_3': charact_3, 'charact_4': charact_4}
fields = ['Описание', 'Слово', 'Транскрипция_1', 'Транскрипция_2', 'Перевод', 'Значение_1', 'Значение_2', 'Значение_3',
          'Значение_4']
with open('example_3.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    pisar = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\r')
    # Проверяем, находится ли файл в начале и пуст ли
    f.seek(0)
    if len(f.read()) == 0:
        pisar.writerow(fields)  # Записываем заголовки, только если файл пуст
    pisar.writerow([stprage['zagol'], stprage['word'], stprage['trans_1'], stprage['trans_2'], stprage['perevod'],
                    stprage['charact_1'], stprage['charact_2'], stprage['charact_3'], stprage['charact_4']])
```

Comment: Ну как минимум в первой части у вас цикл (в цикле), при этом значение `perevod` внутри тела цикла вы никуда не записываете, поэтому там остаётся только последнее значение после выполнения кода, хотя печатаются все значения. А вопрос то про какой конкретно список?

Comment: Вставьте слово или несколько слов на английском через запятую...
science,worker,director
наука
работник
директор
Definition of director noun from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
director
/dəˈrektə(r)/,  /daɪˈrektə(r)/
/dəˈrektər/,  /daɪˈrektər/
one of a group of senior managers who run a company
a person in charge of a film or play who tells the actors and staff what to do
a person who is in charge of a particular activity or department in a company, a college, etc.
None
Я ожидаю от программы что обработаются все три слова которые я вставил, а  обрабатывается  последнее.